# issues with Installing gems on chef

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, berkshelf

I am trying to install Berkshelf however it whines that a gem called retryable isn't installed, so I do the following

```
gem_package 'retryable'

gem_package 'berkshelf
```

so why does this keep happening in the chef logs:

```
    Unable to resolve dependencies: berkshelf requires retryable (~> 1.3.3)
---- End output of C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin\gem install berkshelf -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "3.2.2" ----
Ran C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin\gem install berkshelf -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "3.2.2" returned 1
```

Even though I can clearly see that retryable is being installed right here:

```
[2015-01-14T17:55:00+00:00] INFO: Processing gem_package[retryable] action install (go-agent::install line 14)
[2015-01-14T17:55:02+00:00] INFO: Processing gem_package[berkshelf] action install (go-agent::install line 16
```

Whats going on?

EDIT:
After forcing it to install the version I want (v 2.0.0 of retryable, as ridley needs that one as well as berkshelf) I now get this error:

```
[2015-01-15T11:11:20+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout: gem_package[berkshelf] (go-agent::install line 19) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout: command timed out:
---- Begin output of C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin\gem install berkshelf -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "3.2.3" ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
---- End output of C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin\gem install berkshelf -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "3.2.3" ----
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of `retryable` is 2.0.0, so that is the version you are installing via the first `gem_package`. You are using `gem_package` but you don't have an installation of Ruby so it is failing back to Chef's (which it really shouldn't) and I'm guessing there is some kind of dependency conflict happening. Try forcing `retryable` to version 1.3.6, the newest version compatible with Berkshelf.

Comment: I forced it to install version 2.0.0 (ridley requires version 2.0.0 or retryable) and now berk shelf install just hangs; it gives a timeout error.

Comment: Do you have gecode installed system-wide (and tell it to use that)? If not, compiling depselector-lib-gecode as a dependency will take around 20-30m depending on the machine. Is there a reason you aren't using the ChefDK packages?

Comment: Because installing that requires dealing with the `PATH` environmental and that's a can of worms I've opened and found too irritating to deal with when things seemed like they worked, should have worked, tested on the box and worked but didn't work when tried as a part of the chef recipe.

Comment: Windows, We've decided that the best option is just to have an ami(aws)  with it pre-installed along with the path pre-setup.